# Странное поведение php

Tags: php

Столкнулся с очень странным поведением PHP (хотя может быть дело и не в нем).
Скрипт не видит (или не имеет доступа) к файлам и каталогам, находящемся вне каталога, в котором расположен сам скрипт. Данное поведение наблюдается только на сервере, на локалке все работает как надо.

Права на каталоги выставлял на **разрешить все и всем**, но не помогло.
Грешу на какие-то настройки PHP или Apache, но не знаю что именно смотреть.
Подскажите, куда копать?

Сервер - Debian 8
PHP версии 5.6.24.

Comment: @Legionary, название технологий не выделяются кодом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое поведение связано с настройками безопасности.

В данном случае это директива [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

> Ограничивает указанным деревом каталогов файлы, которые могут быть
>   доступны для PHP, включая сам файл.

Comment: да, все так, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 10):

Хороший вопрос.

И ответ на него будет полезен многим пользователям пхп.

Любое странное поведение **всегда** сопровождается сообщениями об ошибках. поэтому надо настроить свой сервер так, чтобы он сообщал обо всех ошибках.

для этого по возможности в php.ini или.htaccess, а на крайний случай - прямо в скрипте через ini_set задать следующие настройки:

- **для сайта в режиме разработки**

  ```
  error_reporting = -1  
  display_errors = 1
  ```

  и смотреть ошибки прямо на экране
- **для сайта в боевом режиме**

  ```
  error_reporting = -1  
  display_errors = 0
  log_errors = 1
  ```

  и смотреть ошибки в логе ошибок веб-севрера

После прочтения сообщения об ошибке необходимость писать в Спортлото с вопросом "Куда мне копать?" отпадает. Равно как отпадает и необходимость в услугах разнообразных гадателей и телепатов, пытающихся по косвенным признакам угадать одну из немногих известных им проблем.

Comment: очень полезная информация, сильно помогла. спасибо большое